# Determining seasonal differencing order

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, arima, statsmodels

I have a situation where I want to automate the process of determining the order of seasonal differencing for time series data. The problem is I have been solving this in python and I didn't find any seasonal unit root tests written in Python. I didn't even find any way of ARIMA order(seasonal) determination technique written in statsmodels for weekly data. So is there any simple and effective way to automate the the seasonal differencing order determining process.

Comment: You look at the autocorrelation function.  As long as it is positive and declining slowly another difference is needed.

Comment: @MichaelChernick But I think in case of seasonal data the values of auto correlation also shows a seasonal pattern and not just goes down linearly.

Comment: Yes, you should look at autocorrelations at the multiples of the seasonal frequency (12,24,36,... for monthly data, for example). Also, it looks like you are already aware of the seasonal unit root tests but do not want to use them because it is tedious to implement them in Python. So what is your real question then? Are you asking for a simple alternative to unit root tests (on topic) or for help with Python implementation of some statistical tests/models (off topic)?

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes I am aware of seasonal unit root tests and also willing to use them. But there is no seasonal unit root test implemented in Python(as per my knowledge). So if you know any alternative to using seasonal tests to determine differencing order or if I am missing on already implemented unit root test please let me know.

Comment: So are you then asking to suggest alternatives that are already implemented in Python? Or are you willing to implement them yourself? The former would be off-topic and also I suppose there are not that many people on this site that use Python (yes, there are some, but not that many, in my impression.) Perhaps you would have better luck on some Python-specific site.

Comment: Yes some already existing Python implementation of any seasonal unit root test or even a library which determines the order of ARIMA model.

Answer (score -1):

The user wants to automate/synthesize ( not look at ) the information in the autocorrelation function. This is precisely what AUTOBOX ( a piece of software that I have helped to develop) does. Pattern recognition requires carefully honed heuristics used iteratively. I would suggest that you create a set of time series via simulation ( including outliers) and test them with the free version of AUTOBOX and study the results as interim steps are fully disclosed. In this way you might be able to program/reproduce the results. There is no simple procedure that can be used because it all depends on the sample size , the impact of anomalies . the impact of level shifts , the impact of seasonal pulses , the impact of local time trends , the impact of parameters changing over time , the impact of non-constant errors variance , non-seasonal ARMA structure .. to name a few of the considerations.

Comment: I second your thoughts on the complexity of time series forecasting. I would like to use AUTOBOX but I am looking for python specific solution. Let me know if you have any api written in python.

Comment: It might be possible to migrate AUTOBOX to a python environment as it has moved everywhere when needed. Contact the folks at AFS and tell them your needs..

Comment: It is great that you educate new users on complexities of real-world time series. However, the user asks specifically for a simple solution, something that works. Trying to transfer the whole sophisticated AUTOBOX machine to Python does not appear to be the desired kind of solution. Therefore, I think your answer serves better as a comment.

Comment: My answer contained  "There is no simple procedure that can be used "